# What does the community think about the recent review queue change?

Tags: discussion

A few minutes ago, [SE has raised the rep threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/148043) for answers to not appear in the late answer review queue. This resulted in a 3.5k long review queue.

What do you think about this?

(I'll intend to use this as a vote, so I am going to write two answers myself, but please feel free to write your own answers.)

---

Edit: Nevermind, can't be changed anymore.

> @Sven: Reverting won't help, I'm afraid. The damage has been done. I have gone over to pitch in on Server Fault as an act of penitence. –  Jon Ericson♦ 2 mins ago

Comment: In some weeks it will disappear. I don't think it is problematic. Especially compared to previous big "projects" on the close queue.

Comment: Looks like a couple of months work in the review mines ...

Comment: Gah!  *[runs away]*

Comment: If those late answer were never reported, we cant assume they are good? And thus ask SE to directly clear the queue ? We are IT, and its a simple db.

Comment: @yagmoth555: The SE team says it can't be undone. I don't claim to understand how the review system works so I've to take their word for it. Surely it's not *really* impossible, but if they have to first create a piece of software for this, it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: I'm optimistic about the change, but I'm going to reserve final judgment until the queue clears and we can see how many reviews it generates on a normal day.

Comment: Er.  I'm now banned from reviewing for two days.  ;)  Glowing product endorsements from four years ago all look alike to me, it seems.  So, you know.  If you tend to click through to the question, don't let the 3,000 items in the queue stop you from taking the time to click through.

Comment: @Sven I think everything can undone, but why? Now the "late answer" queue will be larger, the transient problem can be handled very easily. I would also very gladly help you, but unfortunately... ;-)

Comment: @KatherineVillyard I've unbanned you.  Ridiculous doesn't even begin to cover it.

Answer (score 9):

I was just asked to [review](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/225413) one of my own answers from years before I registered on this site. That felt a bit weird.

But judging from the other things I saw in that review queue, it seems like the change is a sensible one.

I found posts that needed to be upvoted, posts that needed to be downvoted, posts that needed to be flagged, and some that needed no action.

I hope that the change doesn't mean that new posts which enter the queue have to wait in the review queue until it has been cleared.

Comment: No, seen post from yesterday, the review seem random in the 3k items

Answer (score 5):

I think this is lovely.  I almost have a hard-to-get moderation badge out of it (because the queues besides first posts and close votes are very sparse here).

But no, the actual reason this is good is because in the hundreds of those reviews I have done, I have actually found a lot of crap.  I've flagged a bunch of spam and non-answers and fixed a lot of things that needed formatting edits.

I also found a lot of zero-score accepted answers and other things to vote up.

I'm not sure if it should be raised any higher, but this was definitely a useful exercise.

Comment: Zero score accepts http://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=isaccepted%3ayes%20score%3a0

Answer (score 4):

Install Addblock plus and use it to hide the element

```
serverfault.com##.edit-count.unread-count
```

Magically there are no reviews required.

Comment: I did this before becoming a mod, but removed it afterwards. Might start it again ...

Answer (score 2):

Badges for everyone!!!  <s>Just click "No Action Needed"!!!</s>

Comment: In the first-post or late-answers queue it could be useful to click up everytime, if there are no major problems with the post. This is a reward, which motivates the newbie on his first steps in the site. You don't need to click "No Action Needed", click always up, with the exception if the post is crap (then click down + VtC/lowquality flag + advice to the newbie, in *human* style).

Comment: no I think the exact opposite- downvote unless it really is a good answer- this keeps up answer quality.  NAN is good when its marked as an answer already.

Answer (score 2):

The point seems to be to "fix" the amount of crappy answers to old questions by users that can't (or are too lazy) to comment.  I see this as a positive thing.